# Using oauth-4-laravel for Facebook login - what is $code referring to?

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, laravel-4

it is kinda dum, but i'm really stuck on this. Im trying to use https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel for FB login on my Laravel project. I'm looking at these PHP code samples:

```
...

// get data from input
$code = Input::get( 'code' );

// get fb service
$fb = OAuth::consumer( 'Facebook' );

// check if code is valid

// if code is provided get user data and sign in
if ( !empty( $code ) ) {

    // This was a callback request from facebook, get the token
    $token = $fb->requestAccessToken( $code );

...
```

What is `$code` referring to? I just can't figure this out :/

My idea is to use JavaScriptSDK for user login and after that send a request with just-logged-in userID to my server where additional user info should be acquired from FB and stored. So is them `$code` some attribute from `authResponse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$code` is a query-string-supplied variable that is set by Facebook when they redirect your user back to your application, after they've authorized you to use their account.

The application then makes an API call to Facebook with that code in order to get the OAuth token.